# Flashing ESP8266 over WiFi whith samrtphone?

Tags: programming, esp8266, flash

I'm working on a project in which an ESP8266 is the brain of the device. I want to add new features to the device controller later but this requires that the user open the controller and reprogram the ESP8266.

I want the user to be able to update the firmware with his smartphone (maybe through an application). How can I do that? Is this possible with this chip?

Comment: yes, you can use an http POST to push in a new firmware, look at the OTA examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ESP8266 OTA can be performed through a web browser as detailed [in the ESP8266 OTA information page](http://esp8266.github.io/Arduino/versions/2.0.0/doc/ota_updates/ota_updates.html).

Since a smartphone has a web browser I can see no reason why you can't use that.